# ANTLR syntax error depending on where a rule is defined

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am a newbie to parsing and ANTLR, so apologies in advance if this is a silly question. I am trying to use ANTLR to parse logical formulae (involving AND, OR, NOT). I have the following grammar

```
grammar LTL;

ltl: ltl_or | ltl_and | ltl_not | Atom;

ltl_and: OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY And OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY;
ltl_or: OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY Or OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY;
ltl_not: Not OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY;

Or: 'Or' | 'or';
Atom: (~('{' | '}'))+;
And: 'And' | 'and';
Not: 'Not' | 'not';
OPEN_CURLY: '{';
CLOSE_CURLY: '}';
```

My test case is `{ABCD()}Or{AB CD()}`, which I expect should be parsed as a valid `Or` formula with two atoms. And that does happen with the grammar above. However, If I swap the positions of the `Or` rule and the `Atom` rule, as follows:

```
Atom: (~('{' | '}'))+;
Or: 'Or' | 'or';
```

I get the error

```
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input '{ABCD()}Or'
```

Could someone please provide some pointers?

Comment: I’m a newbie as well, so just a guess from looking at the docs :  the ordering is important.  Since `Atom` Is any sequence of non-brace characters, the text `Or` becomes interpreted as an `Atom` Rather than an `Or` token.  So the parser is looking for a `OPEN_CURLY ltl CLOSE_CURLY Atom`, which it can’t find.

Comment: Yup, my mistake was that I didn't know the tokenizer ran first, and would come up with a list of tokens that matches its preferences. The parser isn't in the picture yet.

Comment: Well, that's because rules for `Or` and `Atom` are lexer rules. For Antlr4, the "rule" is "Match the longest lexer rule. If there is more than one lexer rule that matches, pick the first." `Or : 'Or' | 'or';` will never match. Always print out the tokens to your parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactored version of your grammar that correctly handles the input you've provided, and takes advantage of other ANTLR idioms that (hopefully) make it easier to read and maintain.  (With comments to indicate what some changes were made.)

```
grammar LTL
    ;

// *almost* always a good idea to have a start rule that 
// consumes everything up to EOF to prevent
// premature termination of parsing input
ltl_start: ltl EOF;

// *IF* you really want to allow a "naked" ATOM 

// ltl_start: (ltl | ATOM) EOF;

// since it seems ltls are always wrapped in curlies, 
// I've refactored them a bit to simplify also
// used labelled alternatives that are generally easier to read 
// Note, you can use literals in your rules that match token rules 
// and ANTLR will match them up I find this frequently makes the
// grammar easier to read.
ltl
    : ltl OR ltl   # ltl_or
    | ltl AND ltl  # ltl_and
    | NOT ltl      # ltl_not
    | '{' ATOM '}' # ltl_atom
    ;

// Symbols
OPEN_CURLY:  '{';
CLOSE_CURLY: '}';

// keywords
OR:  'Or' | 'or';
AND: 'And' | 'and';
NOT: 'Not' | 'not';

// place ATOM *after* keywords to prevent keywords being misidentified as ATOMs
ATOM: ~[{}]+; // Another way of saying "Atom: (~('{' | '}'))+;"
```

Though not really necessary, I prefer to name Lexer rules in all-caps so that really stand out from parser rules (individual taste)

For Lexer rules, it's very common to have multiple lexer rules that *could* match a particular sequence of characters (i.e. ambiguities).  Avoiding these entirely would be VERY painful, so ANTLR allows for them and resolves the ambiguities with these two rules:

- If more than one Lexer rule matches input, then the one that matches the longest sequence of characters is used.
- If multiple rules match the same length sequence of characters, then the Lexer rule that appears first in the grammar is used.

Comment: Thank you! One reason I used separate rules for AND, OR, NOT etc, was to have separate listener callbacks to handle these cases. Is that not advisable?

Comment: Also, how would this grammar handle 
```{A} And {B} Or {C}```? With curlies, I could require explicit grouping of operands. It seems that wouldn't be possible here as it is written right now.

Comment: the labelled alternatives (ex: `# ltl_or` will each give you a specific Context class for your listeners (yes, it's definitely advisable, it's just that this is another way of getting those separate hooks for listeners and visitors (and is easier to read (opinion), and results in simpler parse trees).

Comment: Not quite sure how to read your second question.  `{A}` would be parsed as a `ltl_atom`.   `{A} And {B} Or {C}` (with the spaces) would be an issue, because your grammar accepts whitespace as part of the `ATOM` lexer rule.  Without the spaces, `{A}And{B}Or{C}` will parse just fine.  Your handling of whitespace is "unusual", but I took it at face value that an atom name was intended to include spaces, as that also fit your examples.

Comment: If you want to allow spaces outside of `ATOM`s in curlies, then, if you can elaborate a bit on examples, I can see what we can come up with to support that.